# regex group matching based on first entry

Tags: regex

As part of regex match,  I am trying to select development / product based on first entry being dd-develop / dd.

eg.
  The given code below always matches development, whether first string entry is "dd-develop" or just "dd".

I wanted to determine second or third word based on first value.

Any Ideas ?

---

Regex:   `(?(?=) (?:development) | (?:product))`

Text:    `dd-develop development product.`

---

Comment: So if the first part is `dd-develop`, you want the pattern to match `development` but if it's just `dd` you want it to match `product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're trying to decide whether to capture "development" or "product" based on the first word. This regex does that:

`(:?dd-develop .*(development).*)|(?:dd .*(product).*)`

If your string starts with `dd-develop`, it captures "development". If it starts with `dd`, it captures "product". To reverse this, just switch the words in the capture group.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/IReNzF/1/)

Comment: Thanks.  Was looking for this response.   It matches perfectly based on first word.   Awesome !!!

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider accepting this answer if it addressed your question, so future visitors know what worked. Welcome to StackOverflow!